# How to retrieve data from Firebird DB with missing user collation?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I've got a Firebird DB (FDB file) that I can connect to just fine. However, one of the tables uses a user-defined collation, which apparently was defined via an fbintl_xyz.dll extension. That extension is not available to me.

Accessing that table consequently results in 
COLLATION UTF8_XYZ for CHARACTER SET UTF8 is not installed

Is there any way around this?

I only need read access, and I don't care about collation support (ordering, upper case/lower case).

Comment: You might get away with casting to character set `NONE` and then casting back to character set `UTF8`; I'm not 100% sure though (eg `CAST(CAST(field AS VARCHAR(4000) CHARACTER SET NONE) AS VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET UTF8)` (note the factor 4 difference in field lengths, this is important).

Comment: Thanks Mark. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I also tried `CREATE DOMAIN utf8_foo varchar(256) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UNICODE_CI;
SELECT CAST(field AS TYPE OF utf8_foo) FROM table;` as per [link](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-cast.html), but to no avail. What's written in the last section there doesn't sound promising. A quick look at the firebird sources also doesn't give much hope.

Comment: I haven't worked with custom collations, so I can only guess. Maybe you can define a collation with the same name that just uses the normal utf-8 collation? Otherwise I suggest you post your question to the Firebird-support mailinglist.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to change the table's/column's definition in system tables so that it uses ie `none` instead of the missing collation?